# What is the AND statement for HTCondor HPC?

Tags: hpc, condor

It seems this HPC is hard to google docs. How does one write an `AND` statement for it? e.g. for `OR` one does:

```
requirements = (CUDADeviceName == "Quadro RTX 6000") || (CUDADeviceName == "NVIDIA A40")
```

would:

```
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m") /\ (CUDADeviceName == "NVIDIA A40")
```

work? What I want is NOT tesla k40m and NOT A40. Anything else is fine.

Gives error:

```
(metalearning_gpu) miranda9~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning $ condor_submit job.sub
Submitting job(s)ERROR: Parse error in expression: 
        Requirements = ((CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m") /\ (CUDADeviceName != "NVIDIA A40")) && (TARGET.Arch == "X86_64") && (TARGET.OpSys == "LINUX") && (TARGET.Disk >= RequestDisk) && (TARGET.Memory >= RequestMemory) && (TARGET.Cpus >= RequestCpus) && (TARGET.gpus >= Requestgpus) && ((TARGET.FileSystemDomain == MY.FileSystemDomain) || (TARGET.HasFileTransfer))
```

Answer (score 0):

For an `AND`/conjuction this seems to work:

```
requirements = (CUDADeviceName != "Tesla K40m") && (CUDADeviceName != "NVIDIA A40")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want `&&` for conjunction.

For a complete tutorial of the classad expression language, see the manual section at https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classads/index.html

Or, there's a YouTube tutorial about the expression language at

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8aHj8q56ik